# Pivot Control Error

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot

I am currently coding an application that involves navigating between pivot control.

There will be a total of 8 pivots. I've already done one and am currently working on the second one. However, when I repeat the same thing as what I did with the first pivot control, an error shows up. Please refer below for the code and the error.

I am new to WP7 development. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;


namespace SGFoodDirectory
{
    public partial class Alcohol : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public Alcohol()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BC_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AlPivot.SelectedItem = BcPivot;
        }

        private void MabukMoney_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AlPivot.SelectedItem = MmPivot;
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PivotItem' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedItems' and no extension method 'SelectedItems' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PivotItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Please comment on down vote. I'm simply confused why the code worked on the first pivot control but is not working on the second pivot control. Any explanation will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't do that - pivots are designed to be navigated by the user using touch. From experience of seeing other apps that do this it is very confusing if the code jumps you to another pivot item on a button click.

Also, having 8 pivot items seems a bit high: this may well cause problems with memory usage as well as the general usability of having to flick your page 8 times to rotate back to the start.

I'd recommend rethinking your application flow using other PhoneApplicationPages so you don't need to do this.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for the recommendation. The Pivot Control list different categories and the buttons are supposed to help the user to be able to navigate to items in the Pivot control easier. Much like a menu pointing to more description.

Comment: ListPicker is a great control to consider in that scenario (it's in the Silverlight toolkit).

Comment: So my proposed option is not viable and not doable in this case?

Comment: After reading through your proposed option, I am let to the assumption that you do not understand the problem. There will be 8 Pivot control. Each pivot control will have around 3 - 4 pivot item.

Comment: Have you got pivots within pivots?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `AlPivot.SelectedItem` rather than `AlPivot.SelectedItems`?  The following snippet navigates from the first pivot item in to the second on button click..

**XAML**

```
 <controls:Pivot Name="PivotTest" Title="MY APPLICATION">
    <controls:PivotItem Name="PI1"  Header="item1">
        <Grid>
             <Button Content="Button" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164,106,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button1_Click"/>
        </Grid>
    </controls:PivotItem>
    <controls:PivotItem Name="PI2" Header="item2">
        <Grid/>
    </controls:PivotItem>
</controls:Pivot>
```

**CS**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PivotTest.SelectedItem = PI2;
}
```

**EDIT**

Ah!  I think I see your issue.  You are trying to set the SelectedItem property of the PivotItem, not the Pivot control.  If I have it correct, you want to move to the appropriate pivot item on button click.

Comment: Using 'AlPivot.SelectedItem' also shows the same error after rebuilding.

Comment: Thanks zombiesheep. Sadly, it works for the first Pivot. However, on the second pivot, the above mentioned error is shown.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do. I am confused why similar code worked for my first pivot but fails to work on the second pivot.